# no data is retrieved after query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to fetch specific records from the database table based on user input but getting no data in the objj. Can anybody specify the error? **objects.all()** is also returning no data.

views.py

````
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from ssr.models import dinucleotides
from ssr.forms import InputForm



# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def searchpage(request):
  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    fm=InputForm(request.POST)
    if fm.is_valid():
      print('form validated')
      Motiff = fm.cleaned_data['Motiff']
      
      obj1=dinucleotides.objects.filter( SSRtype=Motiff)
      objj={'obj1':obj1 }
    return render(request,'result.html', objj)

    
 
  else:
    fm=InputForm()
    return render(request,'search.html',{'form':fm})```



# models.py

from django.db import models


class dinucleotides(models.Model):
    ID = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    Chromosome = models.CharField(db_column='Chromosome', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    SSRtype = models.CharField(db_column='SSRtype', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    Sequence = models.CharField(db_column='SSRsequence', max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    Size = models.IntegerField(db_column='Size', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    Start = models.IntegerField(db_column='Start', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    End = models.IntegerField(db_column='End', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dinucleotides
````

Comment: Have you verified that your database tables have records?

Comment: yes, data is there in database